# Typescript: Recursion file-system lookup

Tags: recursion, node.js, file-system, typescript, lookup

Previously I asked a question to find the best practice of recursively running a function to retrieve all import/export statements of files in NodeJs [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/173560/recursively-find-typescript-files-imported-exported-from-an-entry-point).

After some discussion I'm not satisfied yet, so I'm going to post my rewrote code from what I learned in previous discussion in hope of finding a better approach or simply getting review of my code.

I'm calling `preprocessTSFiles` function which runs `getFiles` with the entry-point and return all its import/export statements plus itself which leads to a recursive call of `getImporters` from `VinylFile` class.

**preprocess-files.ts**

```
import * as path from 'path';
import * as vinyl from 'vinyl';
import { VinylFile } from './file';
import {
  ensureMakeDir,
  isArray,
  isDirectory,
  isEmpty,
  isFile,
  isNil,
  readFile,
  writeFile,
} from './utils';

import { InlineStyles } from './plugins/inline-styles';
import { InlineTemplate } from './plugins/inline-template';

export interface HandlerPlugin {
  (file: VinylFile): Promise<string>;
}

export async function preprocessTSFiles(entryFilePath: string, destDir: string, baseDir?: string): Promise<void> {
  const fileList: string[] = [];
  const plugins = [InlineTemplate, InlineStyles];

  if (isNil(baseDir)) {
    baseDir = path.dirname(entryFilePath);
  }

  const allFiles = await getFiles(entryFilePath, []);

  for (const file of allFiles) {
    for (const plugin of plugins) {
      const newContent = await plugin(file);

      if (newContent != file.content) {
        file.setContent(newContent);
      }
    }

    const currentPath = file.filePath;
    const destPath = currentPath.replace(baseDir + path.sep, '');
    const absDestPath = path.resolve(destDir, destPath);

    file.copyTo(absDestPath);
  }
}

async function getFiles(entryFilePath: string, excludeList: string[]): Promise<VinylFile[]> {
  const entryFile = new VinylFile(entryFilePath);
  const excludeFromList: string[] = [entryFilePath];
  return [entryFile, ...await entryFile.getImporters(excludeFromList)];
}
```

**file.ts**

```
import * as path from 'path';
import {
  ensureMakeDir,
  isDirectory,
  isFile,
  isNil,
  readFile,
  writeFile,
} from './utils';

export class VinylFile {
  private _content: string;
  private importStatementRE = /(?:import|export)\s*(?:(?:\{[^}]*\}|\*|\w+)(?:\s*as\s+\w+)?(?:\s+from)?\s*)?([`'"])((?:\\[\s\S]|(?!\1)[^\\])*?)\1/ig;

  public dirPath: string;

  constructor(public filePath: string) {
    this.dirPath = path.dirname(filePath);
  }

  get content(): string {
    if (isNil(this._content)) {
      this._content = readFile(this.filePath);
    }

    return this._content;
  }

  public setContent(content: string): void {
    this._content = content;
  }

  public copyTo(destFilePath: string): void {
    const dirPath = path.dirname(destFilePath);
    ensureMakeDir(dirPath);
    writeFile(destFilePath, this.content);
  }

  public hasImporters(): boolean {
    this.importStatementRE.lastIndex = 0;
    return this.importStatementRE.test(this.content);
  }

  public async getImporters(excludeFrom?: string[]): Promise<VinylFile[]> {
    const importees: VinylFile[] = [];
    const importStatementMatchIndex = 2;
    let importersMatch: RegExpMatchArray | null;

    if (isNil(excludeFrom)) {
      excludeFrom = [];
    }

    // Reset current index to 0
    // RegEx.test moves this into 1
    this.importStatementRE.lastIndex = 0;
    while ((importersMatch = this.importStatementRE.exec(this.content)) && !isNil(importersMatch)) {
      const importee = importersMatch[importStatementMatchIndex];
      const resolvedPath = path.resolve(this.dirPath, importee);

      if (isDirectory(resolvedPath)) {
        const resolvedIndexFilePath = path.resolve(resolvedPath, 'index.ts');

        if (isFile(resolvedIndexFilePath) && excludeFrom.indexOf(resolvedIndexFilePath) < 0) {
          const resolvedIndexFile = new VinylFile(resolvedIndexFilePath);
          excludeFrom.push(resolvedIndexFilePath);
          importees.push(resolvedIndexFile);

          if (resolvedIndexFile.hasImporters()) {
            importees.push(...await resolvedIndexFile.getImporters(excludeFrom));
          }
        }
      } else {
        let resolvedFilePath = resolvedPath;
        if (path.extname(resolvedFilePath) !== '.ts') {
          resolvedFilePath += '.ts';
        }

        if (isFile(resolvedFilePath) && excludeFrom.indexOf(resolvedFilePath) < 0) {
          const resolvedFile = new VinylFile(resolvedFilePath);
          excludeFrom.push(resolvedFilePath);
          importees.push(resolvedFile);

          if (resolvedFile.hasImporters()) {
            importees.push(...await resolvedFile.getImporters(excludeFrom));
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return importees;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I see your code is more readable after the refactoring.

You had choose better name that clarified the intention. This is a good part.

I think the thought point is the *while* part.

In a functional fashion you could improve the code putting the matching part in a method:

```
getImportStatements() {
  const importStatementMatchIndex = 2;
  const importStatements = [];
  let importersMatch = this.importStatementRE.exec(this.content);
  while(!isNil(impotersMatch)) {
    importStatements.push(impotersMatch[importStatementMatchIndex]);
    importersMatch = this.importStatementRE.exec(this.content);
  }
  return importStatements;
}
```

This will return just a list with the matching strings. The reason for this change is to try to split up the responsabilities in a way that your code will be much easy to read and change.

This method isolate the logic on how you get the list of imports on the source file.

Then you could rewrite the main method removing the while loop and adding the following:

```
this.getImportStatements()
  .map((importee) => (path.resolve(this.dirPath, importee)))
  .map((resolvedPath) => {
    if (isDirectory(resolvedPath)) {
      return path.resolve(resolvedPath, 'index.ts');
    }
    return (path.extname(resolvedPath) !== '.ts') ? resolvedPath += '.ts' : resolvedPath;
  })
  .filter((resolvedFilePath) => (!isFile(resolvedFilePath) || excludeFrom.indexOf(resolvedFilePath) >= 0))
  .forEach((resolvedFilePath) => {
    const resolvedFile = new VinylFile(resolvedFilePath);
    excludeFrom.push(resolvedFilePath);
    importees.push(resolvedFile);

    if (resolvedFile.hasImporters()) {
      importees.push(...await resolvedFile.getImporters(excludeFrom));
    }
  });
```

The principle is to attach on the array returned from *getImportStatements()*, that guarantee to return at least an empty array.

Then it use the javascript array methods to map the strings to full path, filter  and then collect.

Fell free to change the arrow functions in methods to increase the readability of the code.

Comment: I really like what you did with js style of chain of command with arrays.

Comment: How do you merge return of `getImportStatements` with `getImports`? We need them all as an array in one place

Comment: @PRAISER you place the *getImportStatements* call inside the *getImports* removing the while loop.

Comment: I'm talking about how should I put it, I need to return a promise in `getImports` but in `getImportStatements` we're not returning anything!

Comment: @PRAISER in *getImportsStatements* it returns an array, if you look at the code you see that in the last *forEach* statement, it accumulate the *VinylFile*s in the *importees* array, as was doing it in the *while* loop. So if you remove the loop and place the code in my answer, everithing should work as before.

Comment: The last forEach of `getImportStatements` will break the code, cause it's not async and we're running `await`. That being said the function will return nothing and promise chain will break!

Comment: @PRAISER you're right the *forEach* is blocking, but to slow down is the *await* part, but I think this works exactly as in your while loop. Maybe you could wrap the *getImportsStatements* block in a promise that resolve returning the *importee* array, so you can return that promise in the method.